# getColumnIndex(_ID) returns zero, getlong(getColumnIndex(_ID)) = correct value

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So when I use the `int location = cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID)` it always returns zero, despite `long locationId = cursor.getlong(getColumnIndex(_ID)` returns 7. Why is it that I'm getting different values?

```
    if (locationCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        //This is where the problem is happening
        locationId = locationCursor.getLong(locationCursor.getColumnIndex(WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID));
        //=7
        int location = locationCursor.getColumnIndex(WeatherContract.LocationEntry._ID);
        // = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID)` returns `0` which is the index (position) of the `_ID` column in the database table

`cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID))` returns `7` which is the value stored in the column `_ID` of the database table where the cursor is positioned (row) currently.